# Indentificar el error en el script de R

Tags: r

Al ejecutar el siguiente script:

```r
PMG=optimPMG(dLL=10^-10, maxIter=200, TetaStart=rep(x=1, times=1),
             vecSR=list(SR1=c("Pib","dConsumo"),
                        SR2=c("Pib","dConsumo"),
                        SR3=c("Pib","dConsumo")),
             vecLR=c("lPib","Consumo"),
             dataset=Panel$dataset, quantity=Panel$quantity, const=TRUE)
```

Me aparece lo siguiente

> Error in solve.default(t(pomW) %*% pomW):
> system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.18544e-23

¿Me pueden ayudar a saber cuál es el error?

Comment: En realidad no es un error del script, se trata de un error donde la matriz es singular (tiene determinante cero, no es invertible) esto se debe a que existe una combinación lineal exacta entre dos vectores (colinealidad perfecta). Viendo tus datos, tenés PIB y Consumo, visto por el lado del gasto el PIB tiene como principal componente el Consumo en su identidad macroeconómica. ¿Al tratarse de una identidad macroeconómica, qué sentido tiene estimar dicha relación?

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Basándome en esta [respuesta](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76488/error-system-is-computationally-singular-when-running-a-glm), el problema puede venir de que la matriz introducida es singular, es decir, existe gran correlación entre sus columnas, y por tanto no es invertible dentro del proceso de la función `optimPMG`